# Error Fatal: NO se puede encontrar el REMOTE HELPER para 'git+https'

Tags: npm

fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'git+https'

Cuando ejecuto el comando:
npm i

Me aparece el siguiente error:
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'git+https'

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Amigos, ya encontre el error... se trata de la versión de NPM, solo descargue el programa "n" asi como lo escribi.

Con este programa instalas una versión mas actualizada y listo... Fuera error.